# Socket.io Scala client

Tags: scala, websocket, socket.io

I'm looking for a socket.io client for Scala. I'm well aware of [this](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client), but I cringe at the idea of using it in Scala as it wouldn't feel quite natural nor would it allow for an idiomatic implementation. Does any of you, thus, have a suggestion as to where could I find a Scala client?

If so, just the lines for SBT and a link to the doc will suffice as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know any already implemented libraries or apparent solutions for Scala. But I'll present two very simple approaches that should be very easy to use if you have the time to DIY :-)

But of course it really depends on what you want. As you probably already could imagine a plain [WebSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) implementation of Java's standard library can be quite efficient if you need to process simple requests. I found one at [scala-lang.org](http://scala-lang.org) implementing [a server calculating random numbers](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/55). If it is of interest there's also something brewing at the [nightly build](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/util/SocketServer.html) which might reveal some handy tricks.

If you want to go for simplicity and for pure Scala in all its might the Actors (in particular a [RemoteActor](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor%24)) are immensly powerful. It requires Scala on both ends naturally, but it gives you a messaging-system almost instantly. [This](http://youshottheinvisibleswordsman.co.uk/2009/04/01/remoteactor-in-scala/) is a pretty good start-guide if you aren't already familiar with them.

Anyway. If no good library surfaces I hope this helped. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I've got no control over the server side, so my implementation has to be compatible specifically with socket.io. +1 for the ideas, anyway

Comment: @emaster70 If you will use websockets, there is [library](https://github.com/jfarcand/WCS) for that